# examples of toy non-Euclidean geometries

Tags: geometry, big-list

Today I was working on a problem in euclidean geometry, and I found it immensely useful to compare with Fano geometry, for contrast. Are there any other toy geometries like Fano geometry? I think it could be useful to have a repertoire of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Felix Klein considered non-Euclidean geometries, like the hyperbolic and spherical geometry.
These are the spaces of constant curvature: Euclidean with curvature $0$, hyperbolic with curvature $-1$ and spherical with curvature $1$. The hyperbolic plane is a good toy example, compared to the Euclidean plane.

Edit: If you wanted finite geometries, here are some more toy examples:http://www.beva.org/math323/asgn5/nov5.htm.

Comment: Is there a set of axioms that govern the hyperbolic geometry?

Comment: Yes, something is written here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry.

Comment: This hyperbolic geometry seems very complicated. Can I do hyperbolic geometry proofs using just paper?